# Edit return.php in controller of opencart

Tags: php, forms, opencart

Helo!

I have edited return.tpl by removing reason to return and opened or not check boxes, Now the problem is as i have removed those codes but controller is noticing as those were rquired fields which can't be empty so the form is not working, can you help me to modify that code so that controller start working.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of opencart?

Comment: OC version 2.0.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `catalog/controller/account/return.php`

Look at the `validate()` function which is called to check the required fields from the form. Remove the fields from this function which you no longer want to be required.